# How to apply SerializationStreamWriter for storage

Tags: gwt, serialization

Is there an **easy way** to use SerializationStreamWriter for custom purposes without writing an own generator?

(for example html5 storage)

The javadoc of GWT tells very little.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**We are writing an implementation for our current project, which does exactly what you want do: serialize an custom object into string and save it into the localstorage, deserialize the string into an object...**

So, for me, it is **possbile**, to use SerializationStreamWriter for serialization, and use SerializationStreamReader for deserialization in CLIENT SIDE.

**To realize this**,

you don't need a generator for SerializationStreamWriter/SerializationStreamReader, but **a generator for TypeSerializer** (which implements com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase). And this is quiet simple, take a look at com.google.gwt.user.rebind.rpc.TypeSerializerCreator, and use it in your generator. OR, if all your custom objects are referenced in one RPC service, you can just use the generated rpc service's TypeSerializer.

And you must write **a proper implementation of SerializationStreamWriter OR SerializationStreamReader**. Because there has two serialized string formats(request used format and response used format):

IN GWT, you have 
    ClientSerializationStreamWriter, ClientSerializationStreamReader for client side serialization/deserialization; 
    ServerSerializationStreamWriter, ServerSerializationStreamReader for server side serialization/deserialization;

**Client** SerializationStream **Writer** will serialize the object into **FORMAT_1**, and only **Server** SerializationStream **Reader** can read it (deserialize it into object).

**Server** SerializationStream **Writer** will serialize the object into **FORMAT_2**, and only **Client** SerializationStream **Reader** can read it (deserialize it into object).

so what you need to do, if you want to use ClientSerializationStreamWriter to serialize your object, then write a similar implementation of ServerSerializationStreamReader for client side. Or if you want to use ClientSerializationStreamWriter to deserialize the string, then write a similar implementation of ServerSerializationStreamWriter in client side. This is not difficult, because the difference between **FORMAT_1** and **FORMAT_2** is just the order.

Comment: I assume in due course you created [this project](https://github.com/seanchenxi/gwt-storage)?! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

No.

Because the GWT-RPC serialization is asymmetric, it cannot be used for local storage: the server understands what the client sent, the client understands what the server sent, but they won't understand what they themselves wrote.